# Expresso Store: Order Confirmation email template - order date

Tags: expresso-store

Is there any way to get displayed order date in the order confirmation email template? I know about `{order_date}` tag but it comes as unix datestamp and I have no clue how to convert it to regular date.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `format` parameter. You can find the entire list of formatting codes [here](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/quick_reference.html).

Something like:

```
{order_date format="%F %j %Y"}
```

Would output August 15 2014 if you purchased something today.